# Efficiency of multithreading and TCP socket coding

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp

I developed a server, which accepts many incoming TCP client connections, and transfers data between them. Client A may send some data via connection A targeting client B. The server forwards the data to connection B so that client B gets the data.

I am doing my testing on a PC with Intel Core **i7-8700 CPU @ 3.2GHz** and **32 GB RAM**.

I launched **two of these servers**, and have **50 threads** constantly running.

Each thread repeats the following steps at an **interval of 150~300 ms**:

1. Randomly disconnects and connects to one of the servers
2. When connected to a server, the server creates a new record in a SQL Server database.
3. When disconnected from a server, the server updates that record in the database.
4. Sends **16 KB of data** to another randomly picked connection, and receives the 16 KB back.

This is what I observed about the two servers on the Windows Task Manager:

- There is no memory leak, stabilizes around 28 MB.
- CPU usage varies between 8% to 18%.
- Power usage varies between "**moderate**" to "**very high**".

My questions is:

I have not worked with apps with TCP connections and threads before. So I have no feeling on whether these figures look unreasonably high - if they are, then I must have done the coding in a very inefficient way.

Can you tell?

Comment: How many simultaneous TCP connections are active and how many connections are made per second ? Are the 50 threads used to compute client requests? It seems a lot, especially because it is more than the number of simultaneous hardware threads your CPU can support. Are you using 1 thread per client?

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Those TCP connections briefly disconnects from one server then immediately connects with another, so at any time there are probably 40 to 45 active connections. I don't have the number of disconnections and connections per second. One thread per connection, so 50 threads. Not much to computer, just forwarding data from one connection to another connection. Does it help? I know it is hard to quantify, just want to know experts' feeling - does the CPU and power usage look unreasonably high or it is pretty much expected?

Comment: It seems pretty big to me regarding the number of clients and the fact that the number of connection/disconnection appears to be 100~300 per second. My machine with a similar processor can handle >10x more connections (and client) for the same load using an unoptimized sequential Python script on Windows. I think the problem may be the SQL database (rather thant the TCP code). Check the timing with and without it. What is the SQL database? Beside this, do you do all the test in local?

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! Your feedback was invaluable to me! It helped me to realize that it was the database reads and writes that was consuming all the CPU and power. Once I stopped the database hits the load became negligible.